# remote clearcase access on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-plugins, clearcase-remote-client

I am new to Jenkins and need some help.

We have ClearCase and Jenkins running on same machine (windows).
The idea is that I have to develop a plugin which will access ClearCase through Jenkins. Instead of approaching the ClearCase gui and command line is a separate window/machine, we want to do this job in Jenkins through a drop down gui. This gui should use `cleartool mkview...` command and should give list of CC VOBs and labels in dropdown gui.

My questions are:

- Is there any existing plugin which does the same job?
- Can you suggest some steps to proceed further?
- If we like to use ClearCase and Jenkins on different machines, how this point should be considered for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[ClearCase plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin)** already create a view (snapshot or dynamic one).

[image: view config]

[image: dyn view]

If you want to develop your own plugin, you can take ideas from the **[ClearCase plugin sources](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin)**.

ClearCase must be installed on the same server than Jenkins if you want to be able to use any cleartool command.
That doesn't means that the view server or Vob server cannot be elsewhere (even on a Linux server if you want).

Comment: If I am not wrong, it will not detect available branches/labels automatically in a particular VoB. So we have to specify them manually.

Comment: @afzalmd Yes, I confirm.

Comment: Is there any plugin or available hint, which gives information how to extend clearcase so that it detects available vobs in a job or branches in a vob rather than to write them manually?

Comment: @Afzal not that I know of. Again, that would involve modifying the sources of that plugin to support your use case.